# Footer toggle with two images for closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, footer, slidetoggle

Thank you for giving me the opportunity to be helped.

I would like to create a toggle footer (slide pannel).

I found the code below which works fine but I want to be able to close the footer with two different buttons: the same image I used to open (#footer_button) AND another image (a cross) placed inside the content (#footer_content).

How should I proceed to integrate the same function on this image (#footer_button_2) with this code?

Many thanks in advance!

Here is a printscreen: http://hpics.li/cb5b88a.

Here is the code I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var slide = false;
var height = $('#footer_content').height();
$('#footer_button').click(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollPos = docHeight - windowHeight + height;
    $('#footer_content').animate({ height: "toggle"}, 1000);
    if(slide == false) {
        if($.browser.opera) { //Fix opera double scroll bug by targeting only HTML.
            $('html').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
        } else {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
        }
                           slide = true;
    } else {
                           slide = false;
                   }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate them with comas like in CSS: $('#footer_button, #CrossImgID') :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var slide = false;
var height = $('#footer_content').height();
$('#footer_button, #CrossImgID').click(function() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollPos = docHeight - windowHeight + height;
    $('#footer_content').animate({ height: "toggle"}, 1000);
    if(slide == false) {
        if($.browser.opera) { //Fix opera double scroll bug by targeting only HTML.
            $('html').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
        } else {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scrollPos+'px'}, 1000);
        }
                           slide = true;
    } else {
                           slide = false;
                   }
});
});
</script>
```